# Batch script read a file that's continously written

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file that's being continuously written with information like this

> HU/gen/tcfg/target/jacinto/starter/starter_b1.cfg
>
> 32.77  34%  141.59kB/s    0:00:00
>
> 94.64 100%  405.35kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#60, to-check=1002/1097)

It is the output of rsync tool, that copies a folder to another path

I'm trying to write a batch script that reads this file and calculates the total amount of data being copied, focusing on this line

> 94.64 100%  405.35kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#60, to-check=1002/1097)

the number 94.64 being the file size in bytes, so I'm guessing I should extract whatever is before "100%" from the line and add it

But I don't know how to continuously read the file while it's being written at the same time

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible from a batch file AFAIK. If you can redirect the output of the rsync tool to the batch file then it should be doable.

Comment: I would use `tail -v` from cygwin

Comment: @Jon I already use a batch script, that starts rsync in another cmd window, and the rsync output is redirected to a txt file. In my batch script, at the next line that starts rsync, I want to read the txt file and calculate the amount of data that's copied. The reason for this is because I already have the total size of the folder (about 4GB) and I want to write on the console output how much more date is to be copied. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ivaylo Unfortunately I don't have tail on this version of cygwin and I can't install it, if it were for me I would use perl for this job,but I must use win tools

Comment: It could be done with batch, but better to use another scripting language like powershell or VBScript or JScript. Batch cannot add floating point numbers. That could be handled by making sure the fractional portion always has 2 digits and then removing the decimal. But more problematic is the fact that the total size may exceed the signed short maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @dbenham so are you saying that the problem is I batch can't add up to 4,670,791,680? well that's not a issue, because I can make rsync log the data in kb and mb, it's just easier for me to sum bytes than checking whether the data is in kb or mb. The main issue is to make batch read from a file that's being written continuously ... do you have some ideas?

Comment: @Jon I can redirect the output of rsync to a batch file, how can I process the input?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that shows how to read a file while it is being written by another process. This is very similar to what jeb shows, except I have added a generic test to see if the process is complete. It assumes the process maintains a lock on the file throughout the entire execution, and it also assumes 20 consecutive empty lines indicates either the end of file, or else we are waiting for more output from the process. The 20 empty line threshold could be set to any number that works for you.

This solution may not work properly if the process writes partial lines to the file. I believe it is reliable if the the process always writes each line in its entirety in a single operation. Also, the lines must be less than or equal to 1021 bytes long, and they must be terminated by carriage return, linefeed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file=test.txt"

set emptyCount=0
del "%file%

:: For this test, I will start an asynchronous process in a new window that
:: writes a directory listing to an output file 3 times, with a 5 second pause
:: between each listing.
start "" cmd /c "(for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do @dir & ping localhost -n 6 >nul) >"%file%""

:wait for the output file to be created and locked
if not exist "%file%" goto :wait

:: Now read and process the file, as it is being written.
call :read <"%file%"
exit /b

:read
set "ln="
set /p "ln="
if defined ln (

  REM Process non-empty line here - test if correct line, extract size, and add
  REM I will simply echo the line instead
  echo(!ln!

  REM Reset emptyCount for end of file test and read next line
  set /a emptyCount=0
  goto :read

) else ( REM End of file test

  REM Count how many consecutive empty lines have been read.
  set /a emptyCount+=1

  REM Assume that 20 consecutive empty lines signifies either end of file
  REM or else waiting for output. If haven't reached 20 consectutive
  REM empty lines, then read next line.
  if !emptyCount! lss 20 goto :read

  REM Test if output file is still locked by attempting to redirect an unused
  REM stream to the file in append mode. If the redirect fails, then the file
  REM is still locked, meaning we are waiting for the process to finish and have
  REM not reached the end. So wait 1 sec so as not to consume 100% of CPU, then
  REM reset count and try to read the next line again.
  REM If the file is not locked, then we are finished, so simply fall through
  REM and exit.
  (echo off 9>>"%file%")2>nul || (
     set emptyCount=0
     ping localhost -n 2 >nul
     goto :read
  )
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 2):

Like dbenham said, it can be done, but batch isn't the first choice.
Attention, the sample will run in an endless loop.
You need to add a break condition, depending of the file content.

I add the `ping ...` command to avoid, that the process consumes 100% CPU-time

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
< rsyncOutput.tmp (
  call :readData
)
echo ready
exit /b

:readDataX
set "line="
set /p line=
if defined line (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do (
    if "%%b"=="100%%" echo Bytes %%a
  )
)
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
goto :readDataX
exit /b
```