# How to read or copy a file without disturbing the writes from another process?

Tags: python, powershell, file, batch-file, file-io

I need to create a modified copy of a file which is periodically updated by a program not under my control. I can do it with a timed loop, so no file change listening is required.

I'm worried about possible conflicts between writing and reading the file from separate processes simultaneously. **I definitely need to avoid crashing the writer process.**  In the reader process, I can retry in case of problems. I don't know how the writer opens the file, but it seems to open and close it for each new piece of data.

What do I need to consider in this situation? Should I let the OS copy the file first before starting to work on it? The solution should work in Windows. I haven't decided yet, whether it should be written in Python (I'm more familiar with it) or as bat or PowerShell script (the client doesn't need to install anything).

---

I just made a small experiment in Python on Linux with one process doing

```
f = open("data.txt", "w")
f.write("1\n")
input("press enter to continue")
f.write("2\n")
f.close()
```

and the other doing

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
print(f.readline())
input("press")
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

It looks like the reader always sees the original version of the file even when the writer is in the middle of writing and the reader never seems to disturb the writer. Is it a Linux thing? Would it be different when the file contained a large amount of data?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829657/batch-script-read-a-file-thats-continously-written) a batch example of something similar, see the answer by @DBenham

Comment: In short, if you use a file lock, this will indicate to any other opening processes that the file is in-use. The opening processes can check for a lock, and if a lock is in place, it will wait/defer until it is available or expired. It might not be what you want, but it is one way of avoiding conflicts. This obviously is for write-mode stuff, since read-mode can be done on a file that is currently open for write (albeit seeing possibly stale data)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I forgot to say that the writer seems to close the file after each write / append.

Comment: The writer when opening the file says whether you can write or not. Therefore if it allows you then it is saying it can handle it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea.

Comment: How big is the file?  How does the writer app create/write the file?  Can you handle a partially-updated copy of the file, or will that cause problems?  What does the writer application do if you do interfere with its writing/updating the file - crash, corrupt the file, error out? Those are all important considerations in solving your problem.  For example, if the file is small and updates infrequent, you can just make a copy, compare it to the original, and if they're the same, use your copy without worrying if the original got updated.