Why does [Console]::Error.WriteLine appear to hijack For Loop output of Power Shell EncodedCommand in Batch For Loop?
Whenever I use [Console]::Error.WriteLine to force write output to STDErr when embedded in a PowerShell EncodedCommand that's called from inside a Batch Script For Loop, the STDErr text all appears to run as though it were "Front Loaded", whereas ALL of the remaining functions/processes appear to run AFTER all STDErr Output is long completed visually!
I KNOW this to be the case, because after all the output is displayed, the PowerShell EncodedCommand is left in what appears to be a hanging state, but when I Tail the log file, I can clearly see the file executing code which should have already been executed when the visible Output is displayed!  (I also tested sending STDErr to the same log file and indeed - ALL of the STDErr verbiage is processed before the actual processes are finalized.)  Is this standard behavior for intercepting PowerShell command output using Batch Script For Loops?  What am I missing?
Technical Data / Code Examples etc.
Consider this PowerShell Script below.  It is converted to an EndodedCommand - note - I left this conversion fluff out of the example.
  Function Write_Log { Param([string]$textOut) write-Host $textOut; write-Output $textOut | Out-File -FilePath ("$Env:log" -replace '"','') -Append -Encoding default }
  
  #This Function - Write_StdErr is what I am seeing bizarre effects from.  No Errors.
  Function Write_StdErr { Param([string]$textOut) If ([int]$Env:isGiveStatus) {Clear-Host; [Console]::Error.WriteLine($textOut); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 } }
  
  For ($i=1; $i -le 100; $i++) {
    #This line will not be parsed by Batch Script for Loop, but will be displayed to user:
    Write_StdErr "Checking for Object [$i] Values"
    
    #Do Stuff
    
    #This Line is parsed by Batch Script for Loop but not displayed to user:
    Write_Log "Current Object being checked: [$i]" $true
    
    #Do More stuff.
  }
  Exit 0
 }

The Script itself completes beautifully when ran through a For Loop in a Batch Script.

My output when running in the For Loop is ONLY:
Checking for Object [1] Values
Current Object [1] is an AUDIT Object
Checking for Object [2] Values
Current Object [2] Data Found
...
Checking for Object [8] Values
Current Object [8] Data Found



Once the final iteration of the loop in PowerShell completes, it appears the data from the PowerShell process is still remaining to be processed by the Batch Script.
set "isGiveStatus=1" & REM This is to ensure the "Write_StdErr" Function sends Output.

REM This For Loop pulls data into various variables from the PowerShell's STDOut Output using this for Loop.
REM The Write_StdErr function in PowerShell is used to bypass the For Loop's processes and display the text raw to the user.
for /f "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%A in ('Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand !newEncodeCMD!') do (
  cls
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  If "%~7"=="CustomFunc" (
    If "%%~A"=="" (
      Call :WriteOut "The parameter from the PowerShell Script was empty." %log% "Yes"
    ) else (
      REM Sub-Routine of Batch script provided as 8th argument like ":SubRoutineName"
      Call %~8 "%%~A"
      REM Note - Routine called has no values written to the Console - only data is logged to Log file.
      set "Powershell_Rslt=!errorlevel!"
    )
  ) else (
    set "Powershell_Rslt=!errorlevel!"
    REM Echo %%A
    set "%~8=%%A"
  )
)

EDIT
I attempted to implement Aacini's process below and it mostly works beautifully - the only piece left is to figure out how to bypass the 1023 character limit of set /p and go from there. . . I consistently stopped at the 6th iteration of the loop because of this.  Count confirmed in N++. . .  While I do understand I could just simply change the output to have many fewer characters, I'm hoping there's a solution to move beyond this limitation.


In a batch file, the for /F command works this way: first it run the commands in the for body and stores all output in a temporary file. After the commands in for body have ended, then the for loop processes the temporary file.  A possible solution would be to not use a FOR /F loop, but pipe the output to a subroutine that process each line via a goto assembled loop. However, this solution have also its drawbacks...

In a batch file, the for /F command works this way: first it run the commands in the for body and stores all output in a temporary file. After the commands in for body have ended, then the for loop processes the temporary file. So your real-time output of both Stdout and Stderr don't works.
A possible solution would be to not use a FOR /F loop, but pipe the output to a subroutine that process each line via a goto assembled loop. However, this solution have also its synchro problems.
To avoid such pipe problems, just use a temporary file instead of the pipe:
set "isGiveStatus=1" & REM This is to ensure the "Write_StdErr" Function sends Output.

::: REM This For Loop pulls data into various variables from the PowerShell's STDOut Output using this for Loop.
::: REM The Write_StdErr function in PowerShell is used to bypass the For Loop's processes and display the text raw to the user.

REM Execute PowerShell and send its output to an auxiliary file that works like a pipe
REM this is done because the direct reading of lines from a pipeline have other synchro problems
start "The Powershell Process" Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand !newEncodeCMD!  ^>  PipeFile.txt

REM Wait a couple seconds to give the Powershell window chance to start
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul

REM Then, read the "pipe file" in :readLines subroutine in an asynchronous way
call :readLines < PipeFile.txt

goto :EOF


:readLines

SET "line="
SET /P "line="
IF NOT DEFINED line exit /B

for /f "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%A in ("%line%") do (
  cls
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >nul
  If "%~7"=="CustomFunc" (
    If "%%~A"=="" (
      Call :WriteOut "The parameter from the PowerShell Script was empty." %log% "Yes"
    ) else (
      REM Sub-Routine of Batch script provided as 8th argument like ":SubRoutineName"
      Call %~8 "%%~A"
      REM Note - Routine called has no values written to the Console - only data is logged to Log file.
      set "Powershell_Rslt=!errorlevel!"
    )
  ) else (
    set "Powershell_Rslt=!errorlevel!"
    REM Echo %%A
    set "%~8=%%A"
  )
)

goto readLines

Perhaps the start command needs cmd.exe this way:
start "Powershell" cmd /C Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand !newEncodeCMD!  ^>  PipeFile.txt

The waiting for the Powershell window to start can be achieved via waitfor command. Review waitfor /? on screen help.
Note that the end of the loop is when read an empty line. If Powershell can output an empty line, then this method must be changed. Perhaps Powershell can output a line with END at end of the process, and then identify such end line.
If your code is a subroutine that receive parameters (and use param #7 as in: If "%~7"=="CustomFunc" (), then the :readLines subroutine must be called with the original parameters or store such a parameter in a variable and use the variable inside :readLines

Before I attempt an implementation of this - essentially since the file is being written by the Powershell script started in a separate CMD process using the Start command, that can operate on its own without having the entire script held up, and as long as that file is continuously updated, the content is piped in using STDIn redirection upon calling the Routine?  Do I have that understood proper?

Yes, you are right. The core point of this solution is have two processes: the Powershell process that show errors on Stderr (the screen) and redirect output to the pipefile, and the Batch process that read from the pipefile and show results on the screen...

Ok - I will try and find a way to implement this so that I can see how the performance differs - looking forward to seeing this work in action.  I'll let you know how this goes as soon as I can - greatly appreciate your input as always

So . . . In testing this, more than 50% of the time I only get about half of the data redirected to STDin and the process just simply stops, even though the output file generated has all the data expected.  Is this because the data appended to the file has finished, so the redirect to STDin simply ends?

I figured out what's happening!  it appears we are at the mercy of set /p's length limit!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844883/bypass-maximum-length-in-set-prompt-set-p-batch  -  I'll edit my question here shortly (while redacting some of the lengthy bits).  Now to figure out how to split this string prior to putting it into set /p . . .  Otherwise, I think this will work until I can resolve this.

Also - For what it's worth - the PowerShell Write-Host, when redirected from CMD, will write the file in UNIX Line Endings - if I change my script to Write-Output instead, it won't even finish processing the first item from the file.

So - back to my original mention of not getting all the data - I did end up removing a ton of my fluff verbiage so the total output to the file is -LT 750 chars, if I call the routine to process <PipeFile.txt while the powershell script is running still, regardless if it's even starting within 1 or 2 seconds before the powershell script ends, the data pulled in will still be missing some of the information.  Even with utilizing checks found in this answer to ensure more than one empty line may be accounted for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837162/9135863

As I said in the answer, the waiting for the Powershell code to start can be achieved in a better way via waitFor command. To do that, change ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul line by waitFor PSstarted > NUL one and insert the waitFor /SI PSstarted > NUL command in the Powershell code before the FOR loop.

To read long lines: after set /P command have read a chunk of one line, the rest of the line is waiting to be read via the following set /P  commands. In this way, you should continue reading the following chunks of the same line until the last chunk (the one with less than 1021 characters) appears. You can read more about this topic at Processing text files that have unlimited size lines!

In more testing, it appears there were two issues - 1) - The set /p string length which I've solved by shortening the output of the PowerShell command.  2) - The moment the file is being read in as STDIn, it will not get the remaining data of the file, even if the file is updated beyond the first point of the initial read.  Depending on the timeout I apply, if it starts the read when the PS command is at loop item 2, or 3, the PS command continues to update the file, but the file's content isn't appropriately fed into set /p and the rest of the parsing finishes empty. . .

Also, WaitFor isn't permitted in my work environment, so I have to time it based on file existence using a routine on a for /L loop checking for the file and providing a Timeout of 1 second until the file exists, then moves forward, so I know the file always exists - this hasn't been the issue specifically, if that makes a difference.
